# How can I get the memory address of a C++/CX ref type object?

Tags: windows-runtime, c++-cx

Windows Runtime introduced new ref objects that use the `^` notation which is basically a smart pointer according to the docs. I'm trying to output some debugging information and I'd like to print the memory address of one of these C++/CX ref objects. How can I do that?

Comment: Worth a read of this Microsoft article [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2012/09/17/cxxcxpart02typesthatwearhats.aspx)

Comment: Just cast to void* to get a raw pointer value.

Comment: Thanks Hans, I assume that will give the address of the smart pointer? What about the address of what the smart pointer is pointing to?

Comment: No, that gives the value stored by the smart pointer. Which is the address that the smart pointer is pointing to.  If you wanted the address of the smart pointer you would need to use the & operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was given by Hans Passant in a comment, it is: Just cast to `void*` to get a raw pointer value.